# Dynamic DataTemplate via UserControl with Binding Parameter

Tags: c#, dynamic, data-binding, user-controls, datatemplate

I need to use DataTemplate dynamically in a ListView. This datatemplate is an user control. I can call the user control dynamically. But I can not read item from user control.

```
         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate xmlns:local ="using:App4.Components" x:DataType="models:modelAuftrag">
               <local:ucPosListeConteiner Test="{x:Bind auftragNummer}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I share a code aside as an example.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
       (
            "Test",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ucPosListeConteiner),
            new PropertyMetadata("")
       );


    public string Test
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TestProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestProperty, value);}
    }
```

And constructor;

```
 viewModelUcPosListeConteiner model;

    public ucPosListeConteiner()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        model = new viewModelUcPosListeConteiner();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

Runtime;

[System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'App4.Components.ucPosListeConteiner' to type 'App4.Models.modelAuftrag'.
   at App4.Components.ucPosListeNew.GetBindingConnector(Int32 connectionId, Object target)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvenL.png)

If i remove in constructor this.DataContext = this statement, code give not an error. But this time the binding not working in user control.

How do i get outgoing data and binding in UserControl?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved.

I didn't use this.DataContext = this; in Constructor.

Here is xaml code;

```
  <DataTemplate  x:Key="dt3"  x:DataType="models:modelAuftrag">
        <local:ucPosListeConteiner Test="{x:Bind model}"></local:ucPosListeConteiner>
  </DataTemplate>
```

Here is ucPosListeConteiner C# code;

```
    public viewModelUcPosListeConteiner Test
    {
        get { return (viewModelUcPosListeConteiner)GetValue(TestProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); model = new modelPosListe(); model = value; }
    }
```

And i binding the Value with C# in UserControl_Loaded

```
    Binding myBinding = new Binding();

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myBinding.Source = model;
        myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("test");
        myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(txtDeneme, TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
    }
```

Than i can Binding and get import parameter.